# how print modules on web

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
var http = require('http');

function start() {
function onRequest(req, res) {
    console.log("Request received.");
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server has started.");
}
exports.start = start;

var procfs = require('procfs-stats');
var ps = procfs(process.pid);

function sysUsage() {
    ps.io(function(err, io) {
        console.log('My process has done this much io', io);
    });
}
exports.sysUsage = sysUsage;
```

here is my code, I am new in Node.js
how can i print "procfs-stats" and "libCpuUsage" on web?, not in console.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a template engine, there are many (http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/), common ones are:

- [Jade](https://github.com/jadejs/jade)
- [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/)

But it's up to you to choose your preferred for your Node application.

Probably the best option for you is to install and use [ExpressJS framework](http://expressjs.com/) in your Node.js app, it gives you a powerful suite of features to be used in your app.
And of course, it gives you a simple way to add a template engine too.

Please refer to this for your specific needs: [Using template engines with Express](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-template-engines.html)

Comment: Thanks! i will try it!